# How to use an exchangeable instance of a class in (SSR) React (similar to a @Bean in Spring)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, dependency-injection

I am creating an app with Next.js and React (Server Components), in TypeScript. For evaluation and demonstration purposes I want to support two different data sources (delivering the same data, but in different APIs).

Based on the configuration when starting the app, I would like to switch those implementations (which will share the same interface).

In Java/Spring I would do this with two different `@Bean`s, two instances of the same class (or implementing the same interface), which are selected based on the configuration.

What is the recommended way to do this in a Next.js/React app? How do I use dependency injection in react with instances of a class, which remains in memory of the application and is not request scoped?

Answer (score 0):

I use `iti` for DI and `iti-react` to add DI to React components.
You can do the same with Next. In Next you composition root would be an instance in an `_app.tsx`. Then you can use a built in React context to get it.

https://stackblitz.com/github/molszanski/iti-playground/tree/main?file=src%2F_0.business-logic.ts&file=src%2FApp.tsx